# Removing empty sets from lists

Tags: list-manipulation

If I had a list, say,

```
names= {"Andy", "Bob", "Carly", "Sandy", "Jeff", "Tim", "Tom", "Zach"}
```

and I decide to pick a characteristic only a certain of them have, and my input would be something that works, (or think of it as something `WordData["....",",,,,"]`, and my output would look like:

```
{{"Andy", {}, {}, {}, {"Jeff", "Tim"}, {}, {"Zach"}}
```

I know this type of thing probably isn't possible, but just say if it did, how would I only choose the nonempty set?

How would I do this using `Select`?  I know I should select from my set of names, but not sure
(There's probably a different way, but I wanted to continue to practice this function so I can understand it fully).

Comment: Your example list `{{Andy, {}, {}, {}, {Jeff, {{}}, Tim}, {}, {Zach, {}}}` is not a valid _Mathematica_ list. Did you mean `{{Andy}, {}, {}, {}, {Jeff, {{}}, Tim}, {}, {Zach, {}}}` or `{Andy, {}, {}, {}, {Jeff, {{}}, Tim}, {}, {Zach, {}}}`?

Comment: This question [has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562902/efficient-way-to-remove-empty-lists-from-lists/). Follow the link for what seems to be the optimal and general solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming "choose the nonempty sets" means to remove Nulls, this can be done with Select

```
list={Andy, {}, {}, {}, {Jeff, Tim}, {}, {Zach}};
Select[list, UnsameQ[#, {}] &]

{Andy, {Jeff, Tim}, {Zach}}
```

Comment: ,Why `Select[list, Length@# != 0 &]` cannot work?Can you tell me why?Thanks.

Comment: @Tangshutao - This removes the first entry `Andy`. The reason this is removed is because the length of the symbol `Andy` is zero, and so it does not fulfill the criterion (that `Length !=0`)

Answer (score 18):

This works for any level (recursively):

```
{Andy, {}, {}, {}, {Jeff, {{}}, Tim}, {}, {Zach, {}}} //. {} -> Sequence[]
(*
 {Andy, {Jeff, Tim}, {Zach}}
*)
```

Or the cryptic

```
{Andy, {}, {}, {}, {Jeff, {{}}, Tim}, {}, {Zach, {}}} //. {} :> Unevaluated[## &[]]
```

Comment: This should come in handy from time to time.

Comment: Is sequence only used for empty sets or can I use them in other cases?

Comment: @thaibak527 Try this `{{a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}} /. r : {x_, y_} :> Sequence @@ r`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius, `expr //. {} -> Nothing` also works in the first example.

Answer (score 7):

```
{{"Andy", {}, {}, {}, {"Jeff", "Tim"}, {}, {"Zach"}}} /. {} -> Nothing
```

Replace empty sets with `Nothing` gives

```
{{"Andy", {"Jeff", "Tim"}, {"Zach"}}}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is also a prime candidate for `DeleteCases`, here's the equivalent of belisarius method for empty lists nested just one level down:

```
DeleteCases[{Andy, {}, {}, {}, {Jeff, {{}}, Tim}, {}, {Zach, {}}}, {{} ...}, Infinity]
```

> `{Andy, {Jeff, Tim}, {Zach}}`

Comment: Strictly speaking, your solution is not equivalent to belisarius' method, because deeply nested empty lists will not be removed: `DeleteCases[{{Zach, {{{{}}}}}}, {{} ...}, Infinity]`. This topic is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6563973/590388) in details.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for pointing that out, I was thinking "too fast" (or simply too little) so I didn't realize...

Answer (score 3):

As [Leonid says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562902/efficient-way-to-remove-empty-lists-from-lists/), perhaps the most efficient and general solution to this problem is to use `Replace` and `DeleteCases` and I'll document it here as well:

```
Replace[expr, x_List :> DeleteCases[x, {}], {0, Infinity}]
(* {{Andy, {Jeff, Tim}, {Zach}}} *)
```

Read the linked post and the comments for an idea of how this works and the different edge cases that need to be considered (perhaps also look at the revisions to understand the different road bumps with each version).