# Eliminate some value from a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a function that return a table consisting of a 2D points. These points are either {x,y} or {0,0}

```
function[]:=Module[{},(

  If[condition,{x,y},{0,0}](*to avoid the Null as a return I inserted the default value {0,0}*)

)]
```

After this I want to delete the {0,0} points from the table and leave just the {x,y}. How can I do that?

Comment: Mmmm ... After what? You only defined a function. That will do nothing (appart from creating the `DownValues[]` for it)

Comment: It might be easier to leave the Nulls and then delete them later, as done here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34800/1783

Comment: @belisarius, after using this function.