# Problem with Conditionals: Why does mathematica add an extra empty list to my output

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays, timing

I have a set of positions where I want to slice a list of numbers.  If I `Total` the values in that list, and they are greater than or equal to 1, I want to remember the coordinates of the slice.

The following function implements the above, but when If evaluates to `False`, and empty list is appended to the coordinates I wanted to remember.

I understand it is possible to just simply remove the empty lists after the whole data structure is assembled, but I do not want to do this.  The reason is that I am dealing with very large data sets and want to minimize the number of unnecessary operations.  With this in mind, it would be ideal if the empty list was never appended in the first place. [Link to Similar Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34798/removing-empty-sets-from-lists)

```
 tstFunc[pos_, lst_] := 
    Module[{realPulses = {}, start = pos[[1]], stop = pos[[2]], tot = 0}, 
      tot = Total[ lst[[start ;; stop]] ];
      If[tot >= 1, 
        realPulses = Flatten[Append[realPulses, pos]]];
     realPulses]


  pos = {{1, 5}, {10, 11}, {15, 20}}
  highArray = SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@ {4, 5, 10, 11}, 20]

  highSlices = tstFunc[#, highArray] & /@ pos
```

Gives Output

```
   {{1, 5}, {10, 11}, {}}
```

---

I have taken the answers so far and compared their timing, since I tagged the question with timing.

```
 AbsoluteTiming[tstFuncEldo[pos, highArray]]

 {0.000237271, {{1, 5}, {10, 11}}}


 AbsoluteTiming[tstFuncGeorge[#, highArray] & /@ pos]
 {0.000286419, {{1, 5}, {10, 11}}}

 AbsoluteTiming[tstFuncXavier[#, highArray] & /@ pos]
 {0.000388954, {{1, 5}, {10, 11}}}
```

Can any one comment as to why my 'If' statement is appending an empty list?

---

Note:  @eldo solution is the only one that gives the correct result for
     pos = {{11,22}, {270, 270}, {291, 291}}

Comment: I guess `highArray` should be `list` ?

Comment: Perhaps you will find the alternative function `tstFunc2[pos_, lst_] := 
  If[Plus @@ Take[lst, pos] >= 1, pos, Unevaluated@Sequence[]];` useful for "minimiz[ing] the number of unnecessary operations".

Comment: @george2079  Thanks for this.  `highArray` is a sparse array.  Now I have edited.

Comment: @Xavier I tried your function and it did not work for me.  I must be putting in the arguments in correctly.

Comment: @olliepower With the given inputs it works on my side: `tstFunc2[#, highArray] & /@ pos` returns `{{1, 5}, {10, 11}}`. Isn't it the case for you?

Comment: @Xavier it works.  Adding the timing to the question now.

Comment: `Take[list,{a,b}]` and `list[[{a,b}]]` are not the same. `Take` is what you want here...  (the latter happens to give the same result for this example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@ {4, 5, 10, 11}, 20];

pos = {{1, 5}, {10, 11}, {15, 20}};

tstFunc[pos_, lst_] := 
   Pick[pos, Sign@Total@lst[[Span@##]] & @@@ pos, 1]

tstFunc[pos, list]
```

> {{1, 5}, {10, 11}}

Comment: So far yours is the fastest eldo.  Very clever solution to, avoiding `If` all together.

Comment: Or, `Pick[pos, Sign[Total[list[[#]] & /@ pos, {2}]], 1]`.

Comment: @eldo I noticed the `tstFunc` here has a bug in a special case, where `pos` has an element that looks like `{2,2}',  indicating that we should only look at position `2` in high array, and evaluate that there is a '1' in that position.  i'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Do you have this problem also with the other solutions? Could you supply your definitions of `list` and `pos` which cause the problem?

Comment: `list =  SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@  {12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}, 302]`

Comment: `pos = {{11,22}, {270, 270}, {291, 291}}`

Comment: This returns an empty list, when it should return {11,22}, because the sum from `list[[12;;19]]` is `>1`.  I think this happens because of the non-sequential positions in the list

Comment: I updated my answer, now - with `Take` - it should function properly

Answer (score 3):

Just some variants:

```
First@GatherBy[pos, Total@list[[#]] > 0 &]
True /. GroupBy[pos, Total@list[[#]] > 0 &]
Join @@ Last@Reap[Sow[#, Total@list[[#]]] & /@ pos, _?(# > 0 &), #2 &]
```

Answer (score 2):

As an answer to the literal question, you need to return an empty sequence.

```
tstFunc[pos_, lst_] :=
 Module[{realPulses = {}, start = pos[[1]], stop = pos[[2]], tot = 0},
  tot = Total[lst[[start ;; stop]]]; 
  If[tot >= 1, pos, Unevaluated@Sequence[]]]

highSlices = tstFunc[#, list] & /@ pos
```

> {{1, 5}, {10, 11}}

Of course if you find yourself doing this it likely means you didnt want to use `Map` in the first place.

Comment: Note that as of 10.2 we can use `Nothing` in place of `Unevaluated@Sequence[]`